# How do I get the number of months that overlap between a pair of dates and any June-Nov period of any year?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Range1 is 6/1/2021-11/30/2021 and Range2 is 8/15/2021-3/1/2022 (Range2 could be any other range of dates). I want to see how many months of Range2 intersect with Range1. The answer should be 4 because Nov, Oct, Sep and part of Aug intersect Range2. And in my problem even if it was 3 months and 3 days I would say 4 full months. However, I am not counting the first day of the month as a full month.

For example, Range1 is 6/1/2021 - 11/1/2021 and Range2 is 2/1/2021 - 10/1/2021, then the answer should be 4 because June, July, August, and September intersect with Rang1. Note that I am not counting 10/1/2021 so the answer could not be 5.

This was already solved by a helpful user **Scott Craner**

The formula we used is =COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(MONTH(SEQUENCE(P60-P59,,P59)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(SEQUENCE(P60-P59,,P59),SEQUENCE(E81-E80,,E80),0)),""))))

It works flawlessly but I need it to work now for comparing a set of dates such as 2/1/2021 - 10/1/2021 and ANY June-November period of ANY year. In the formula used right now, it doesn't work for finding overlapping months in 2/1/2022 - 7/1/2022 since 2/1/2022 - 7/1/2022 doesn't overlap with 6/1/2021 - 11/30/2021. Can I find the number of matching months between any set of dates and any 6/1/## - 11/30/## period of any year?

Comment: Which one is Range1 or Range2 in the formula mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at it... my approach for finding the overlap for any sets of two date ranges:

1. Convert the date ranges a - b and c - d to number of months since 1900
2. Lets call these month-counts a' - b'  and c' - d'
3. So `a' =(YEAR(a)-1900)*12 + MONTH(a)`, e.g. with a=1/1/2020 then a'=1441
4. To ignore the 1st day of every month, add `-(DAY(a)<2)` to above formula
5. Assuming b' > a' and d' > c', then the overlap is MIN(d',b')-MAX(c',a')+1
6. If the above is negative, there is no overlap

Note, I am using algebra variables instead of cell addresses to simplify the math.

Ps. If you want to nerd out in Excel, use the intersect operator (a space character) to intersect column ranges (representing the months since 1900) in a blank column, then count the number of blanks e.g. `=COUNTBLANK(Z1441:Z1446 Z1443:Z1447)` would give 4. This could be really useful for multiple date ranges, as you can intersect any number of excel ranges. To convert the month count date range (a' to b') to a row range, use `=INDEX(Z:Z,a'):INDEX(Z:Z,b')` so that finally the overlap count is `=COUNTBLANK(INDEX(Z:Z,a'):INDEX(Z:Z,b') INDEX(Z:Z,c'):INDEX(Z:Z,d'))`.